# Dtrace print parent process command

Tags: macos, parent-child, dtrace, mach, xnu

I'd like to have a script that for each new running process, prints its starting command, as well as its parent process.

i'm using the following probes :

```
proc::posix_spawn:exec-success,proc::__mac_execve:exec-success
```

From within the script body, command line string is built from `curproc->p_dtrace_argv`.

parent pid (ppid) is also available, but so far I haven't managed to figure out how to extract the parent process name (preferably full name that can be taken from parent argv[0]).

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: here's 2 examples (my format is pid,ppid,date, commandline)          71414 1 2016 Mar  2 17:50:40 xpcproxy com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64         
71414 1 2016 Mar  2 17:50:40 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/CVMCompiler 2

Comment: Since the `exec` probe fires in the context of the old process before the `exec-sucess` probe fires after the `exec` call succeeds, can you do something like `self->pexecname = execname;` to save the parent execname under the `exec` probe, then retrieve it under the `exec-success` probe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the execname of the process prior to the call to `exec()` in the `proc:::exec` probe.  That will be the name of the executable that called `fork()` and will match the `execname` of the parent process.

I tested this on a Solaris 11 installation:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

proc:::exec
{
    self->pexecname = execname;
}

proc:::exec-success
/ self->pexecname != 0 /
{
    printf( "execname: %s, parent execname: %s", execname, self->pexecname );
    self->pexecname = 0;
}
```

It produced the following output:

```
dtrace: script './exec.d' matched 2 probes
 CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
   6  12486         exec_common:exec-success execname: utmp_update, parent execname: gnome-pty-helper
  14  12486         exec_common:exec-success execname: bash, parent execname: gnome-terminal
  15  12486         exec_common:exec-success execname: ls, parent execname: bash
```

Updated per comments:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

proc:::exec
{
    self->pexecname = execname;
    self->parent_args = (build parent args off curproc here)
}

proc:::exec-success
/ self->pexecname != 0 /
{
    printf( "execname: %s, parent execname: %s", execname, self->pexecname );
    self->pexecname = 0;
    self->parent_args = 0;
}

proc:::exec-failure
/ self->pexecname != 0 /
{
    self->pexecname = 0;
    self->parent_args = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've successfully integrated your code in my script. are there any other types of information I can access in `proc:::exec` probe ? It would be nice to have the parent process command line as well (acquired by argv array)

Comment: @Zohar81 The arguments of the child process prior to calling `exec` should be the same as the parent's arguments.  You can build the arguments off `curproc->p_dtrace_argv` for the parent just as you do for the child.  See the updates.  And to be complete, I also added cleanup to `self` for in case the `exec` call fails.

Comment: Hi again, after porting argv parser to your script, I've encountered some invalid addresses. maybe you can address to my sequel question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794993/dtrace-invalid-address-of-curproc-p-dtrace-argv-when-probing-procexec-succes. thanks